# SSL Manager/Key Configuration User in Jmeter

Tags: configuration, key, ssl-certificate, jmeter-3.2, jmeter-4.0

I have a .p12 certificate which i want to use in my JMeter HTTPS request. I have converted this .p12 file into .jks and tried to implement through key configuration but this is not working out and getting I am getting HTTP 403. can anyone tell me exact procedure which i should follow this.

Jmeter Version tried : 3.0,4.0

Jmeter Log:

```
018/05/21 09:12:56 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test! 
2018/05/21 09:12:56 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [] 
2018/05/21 09:12:56 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [] 
2018/05/21 09:12:56 INFO  - jmeter.config.KeystoreConfig: Configuring Keystore with (preload:True, startIndex:0, endIndex:1, clientCertAliasVarName:'key1') 
2018/05/21 09:12:56 INFO  - jmeter.util.JsseSSLManager: Using default SSL protocol: TLS 
2018/05/21 09:12:56 INFO  - jmeter.util.JsseSSLManager: SSL session context: per-thread 
2018/05/21 09:12:56 INFO  - jmeter.util.SSLManager: JmeterKeyStore Location: C:/Jmeter/Jmeter-3.0.0/certificates/01012018b.p12 type pkcs12 
2018/05/21 09:12:56 INFO  - jmeter.util.SSLManager: KeyStore created OK 
2018/05/21 09:12:56 WARN  - jmeter.util.keystore.JmeterKeyStore: Did not find all requested aliases. Start=0, end=1, found=1 
2018/05/21 09:12:56 INFO  - jmeter.util.SSLManager: Total of 1 aliases loaded OK from keystore 
2018/05/21 09:12:56 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true,*local*) 
2018/05/21 09:12:56 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group 
2018/05/21 09:12:56 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 2 threads for group Thread Group. 
2018/05/21 09:12:56 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error 
2018/05/21 09:12:56 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group number 1 threads 2 ramp-up 0 perThread 0.0 delayedStart=false 
2018/05/21 09:12:56 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1 
2018/05/21 09:12:56 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started 
2018/05/21 09:12:56 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1 
2018/05/21 09:12:56 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-2 
2018/05/21 09:12:56 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Stored: NGDA_new.csv 
2018/05/21 09:12:56 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHCAbstractImpl: Local host = rm101jmp01 
2018/05/21 09:12:56 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl: HTTP request retry count = 0 
2018/05/21 09:12:58 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Stored: keystoreFile.csv 
2018/05/21 09:12:58 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC3Impl: HTTP request retry count = 0 
2018/05/21 09:12:58 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1 
2018/05/21 09:12:58 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1 
2018/05/21 09:12:58 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-2 
2018/05/21 09:12:58 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-2 
2018/05/21 09:12:58 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test 
2018/05/21 09:12:58 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Close: keystoreFile.csv 
2018/05/21 09:12:58 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Close: NGDA_new.csv 
2018/05/21 09:12:58 INFO  - jmeter.config.KeystoreConfig: Destroying Keystore 
2018/05/21 09:12:58 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,*local*)
```